# How to get System.Diagnostics to work in a Blazor application on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, .net-core, blazor

I am trying to use Debug.WriteLine in a Blazor application on Ubuntu Linux. When I run the program with `dotnet run` or when using `F5` to use the debugger, the program works fine but the debug statements won't work. The editor I use is Visual Studio Code.
I have seen similar questions but none of them address this issue on Ubuntu or other Linux distributions.

Here is a constructor and a method of a DamageCalculator class in my code which call the Debug.WriteLine method:

```
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    .
    .

    public DamageCalculator()
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("Created an instance of DamageCalculator");
    }
    public void CalculateDamage()
    {
      Roll = Roll3Dice();
      Debug.WriteLine("Rolled the dice with roll: " + Roll);
      Damage = (int)(Roll * Multiplier)
    }
```

The csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.4" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The launchSettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "damage_calculator": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The launch.json for vscode:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "blazorwasm",
      "name": "Launch and Debug Blazor WebAssembly Application",
      "request": "launch"
    }
  ]
}
```

Does anyone knows why it does not work and how to get this to work?

Comment: Where/how are you looking for the output?  This isn't Console.WriteLine().

Comment: I expected to see output in the terminal from which the program is executed actually.

Comment: No, in Windows you need to run WinDbg, or Visual Studio. Maybe VS Code has an 'Output Window' for capturing debug output. But  try Console.WriteLine() instead. Ony for Server side code (API) of course.

Comment: In WebAssembly: look in the Browser JS console.

Comment: Console.WriteLine() is indeed working inside the browser. Debug.WriteLine does not work probably because it is trying to write to the stderr and it can't do that in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `Debug.WriteLine` functionality I suggest to use the build in logger.

It works cross platform and you can configure, by environment variables:

- the severity level to log (trace, debug, info, warning, error, critical)
- the medium to log to (disk, console)
- specific platform capabilities, like use of systemd (linux), eventlog (windows) etc.
- provides one-stop-shop

It also logs to the browsers console in a Blazor - PWA:

[image]
(firefox console image, edited with paint)

In most .net core projects it's enabled by default.

#### Usage API controller

```
public class CommandController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<CommandController> _logger;
    public CommandController(ILogger<CommandController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Hi there!");
    }
}
```

#### WPA Blazor:

```
@inject ILogger<Index> logger
<!--  html stuff -->
@code {
    protected async override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        logger.LogDebug("hellow!");
    }
}
```

In blazor it not always works out of the box. See this page for details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/logging?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly

#### Config

As for blazor, you might need to add this line in your program.cs:

```
builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
```

Normally, it goes accompanied with the default log settings in the application.json:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer, I going to use this built in logger in that case. Do you have any more information on why the Debug class does not work on Linux?

Comment: Hi, no, not really. For that matter, it actually surprises me that it doesn't. Things like `Console.WriteLine` and such all work out of the box. I don't see why `Debug` should not be working. I also did not find any information on it not being available on linux - so, it might just work, and maybe you're case is really specific..

Comment: It has something to do with Debug.WriteLine trying to write to stderr in the browser.

Comment: Hmm... that's still odd since I believe stderr, is common on most OS-ses.